# Can someone explain this dynamic object spread operator syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have an *object* that needs keys to be *dynamically* added upon values being present in the scope.

```
{
        ...someValue && {value: someFunction(value) }
}
```

Where if `someValue` is present, the key `value` gets added to the *object* after being run through `someFunction`

For some reason, the spread operator makes more sense to me being placed before the `value` key, like this:

```
        someValue && ...{value: someFunction(value) }
```

but of course this is wrong?

Could someone explain the syntax behind this?

Comment: Why you use spread operator? If you have `const valueObject = { value1: "value1" }`, then you want to push new property to the object, you can easily just do this `valueObject.value2 = someFunction(value)`, rite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object literals may only contain:

(1) Key-value pairs, eg `prop: 'val'`, or

(2) A spread object (with `...` on the left hand side, with the right-hand side evaluating to an object / expression)

So if you have

```
{
    someValue && ... { value: 'val' }
}
```

this is not valid, because `someValue` *alone* can't be evaluated as the start of a key-value pair, or as the start of a spread expression.

Comment: why is it my function is being executed before storing my value in the new object?

Comment: The `someFunction` call must be evaluated to an expression before the `value` property can be put on the object, so the `someFunction` needs to finish and return a value first.